# Why does nltk no longer load the model file?

Tags: python, nltk

> Setup : Python 3.4 on Anaconda , Windows 10 IPEC 64 bit VM  NLTK
>   version 3.0.2, stanford-parser-3.5.2

---

I successfully implemented a function yesterday and got it working. Here is the code :

```
def parnow(temp_in):
    import os
    from nltk.parse import stanford
    java_path = "/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.8.0_05/bin/java.exe"

    os.environ['STANFORD_PARSER'] = '/stanford'
    os.environ['STANFORD_MODELS'] = '/stanford'
    os.environ['JAVAHOME'] = java_path

    parser = stanford.StanfordParser(model_path="/stanford/parser/edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz")
    sentences = parser.raw_parse_sents((temp_in))

    for myListiterator in sentences:
        for t in myListiterator:
            return(t)
```

This was working fine yesterday and I made a couple of test runs. This morning, when I ran the same function, with for example `parnow("This is a test.")` I get an error message saying "**NLTK was unable to find the gs file!"** .

---

This is what I've tried :

- Checked the path to the file for spelling errors or alike.
- Reloaded Module, Reloaded Kernel, Restarted Spyder
- Re-copied the path and pasted it again.
- Replaced the file with a backup copy.
- Checked code history but saw no changes made.
- Placed a character in the path. When I do this, I get the "**raise OSError**". When I undo this change, I get the missing file error again, which shows me that the NLTK somehow sees the file afterall.
- Used `C:\\stanford\\parser\\edu\\stanford\\nlp\\models\\lexparser\\englishPCFG.ser.gz` as path.
- Went step by step without function and confirmed each line to make sure no errors where present before setting parser.
- Copied file to another folder, changed path.
- Changed file name.
- Checked permissions of folder / file.
- Checked if file was in use/locked for some reason.

[EDIT] Error message :

```
parnow("This is my last resort")
Out[3]: Tree('ROOT', [Tree('NP', [Tree('NNP', ['T'])])])Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\formatters.py", line 339, in __call__
    return method()

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\nltk\tree.py", line 726, in _repr_png_
    subprocess.call([find_binary('gs', binary_names=['gswin32c.exe', 'gswin64c.exe'], env_vars=['PATH'], verbose=False)] +

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\nltk\internals.py", line 546, in find_binary
    binary_names, url, verbose))

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\nltk\internals.py", line 540, in find_binary_iter
    url, verbose):

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\nltk\internals.py", line 519, in find_file_iter
    raise LookupError('\n\n%s\n%s\n%s' % (div, msg, div))

LookupError: 

===========================================================================
NLTK was unable to find the gs file!
Use software specific configuration paramaters or set the PATH environment variable.
===========================================================================
```

Comment: Can you isolate and unpack the source of the problem, and give the full error message? I.e. if the problem is in the call to `stanford.StanfordParser()` (you don't say if it is or not), make the minimal example that should load it but still fails (do _not_ embed it in a function definition). Also `"/stanford"` depends on the current Windows drive letter, right? It could be `C:\stanford` or `D:\stanford` or whatever.

Comment: Do you know what "the gs file" refers to, by the way? I don't use the Stanford parser...

Comment: @alexis : added the full error message. I said that when I add a character to the path then it gives a different error message, thus I assume the problem must be right there. 

In my case the path refers to :

`/stanford (Python) == C:\stanford (Windows)`
`C:\\stanford (Python) == C:\stanford (Windows)`

The gs file probably refers to the "**englishPCFG.ser.gz**" file, which is extracted from  the "**stanford-parser-3.5.2-models.jar**"

Comment: Ok, now please unpack your function to simplify matters. The error arises when looking for a different file, so it's not clear what's going on. Also, it looks like it occurs when iPython (or a notebook?) Is trying to call a custom formatter. So I suspect the reason it suddenly stopped working is that you forgot to add some display-related "magic". Anyway, **unpack your code**. And try calling it from a regular script with regular text output.

Comment: By the way, write your paths as raw strings and you won't have to double the backslashes: `r"C:\stanford"`.

Comment: @alexis : Yes , unpacking the function and then running the script works. Raw strings as path too.

Comment: So have you resolved the problem? I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: @alexis : no . everything works when it's not in the function. once it's in a function, it no longer works. I have 11 other functions that use nltk and other modules without any problem and I can't use this if it's not inside the function.

Comment: You're saying you can get it to run by taking this same code and running it without putting it in a function? I find that hard to believe. There must be some other difference-- how do you execute each version?

Comment: @alexis : yes . I use this : `temp_in = "james was here. he was a very bad person."` on either version and it only works when not in the function.

Actually I have both in a script. To run the function, I call `parnow()`    ... I changed the function and use the above value with the string. After that, the "no" function part runs as well... Even if I place the part before the function, it doesn't matter. Only the outside function code will give me no error.

f5 to execute

Comment: I'm not sure I can make sense of your explanation, but for sure I could make sense of your **code** if you include it. Edit your question to make it into a *complete* script that you can run; it's presumably only one more line for the function version, but **add the non-function version that works.** Then explain how you run it. Clearly you're using IPython and/or a Notebook; are you running it exactly the same way when it works and when it doesn't? I'll bet that's the real source of the problem.

Comment: @alexis : sorry, just ran it again now and it works without issue... I have no idea what happened. I left the entire code right there and did other stuff and all of a sudden it works fine now ! I changed nothing.

Comment: Don't worry, it was kind of inevitable since what you were describing was impossible. :-)

Comment: I has a similar issue with ipython yet in python invoked from the command line there was no problem.

Maybe that will help narrown down the issues ....

Comment: Isn't gs stand for 'ghostscript'? I has the same issue when it wasn't installed.